# Matlab Cuda Block and Thread IDs

Tags: matlab, indexing, cuda

I'm having some strange issues with Matlab and CUDA.  Basically, I have this code for CUDA which prints the following

1. Local Thread ID
2. Local Block  ID
3. Local Block Dimensions
4. Global Thread ID

**CUDA Code**

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//device functions
 __device__ int getGlobalidx_1d_1d()

{
    return blockIdx.x *blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
}

//kernels
__global__ void kernel_1D_1D()
{
    printf("Local thread ID: %i  Local Block ID: %i, Local Block Dim: %i, Global Thread ID: %i\n", threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x, blockDim.x, getGlobalIdx_1D_1D());

}

int main()
{
printf("\nLaunching kernel as 1D grid of 1D blocks...\n");
kernel_1D_1D<<<dim3(2,1,1), dim3(10,1,1)>>>();
cudaDeviceReset();

return 0;
}
```

This works all fine and well

http://postimg.org/image/4tllso2tx/

However when I do the same in Matlab, things get all screwy

I should get a matrix with,

1. Blocks 0-1
2. Threads 0-9
3. Global ID 0-19
4. Block Dim 10 Across

in other words

- 0....0....0......0......1....1....1......1
- 0....1....2......9......0....1....2......9
- 0....1....2......9......10..11..12....19
- 10..10..10....10....10..10..10....10

Instead, when I supply the Matlab function with arguments 2 and 10 the values are all over the place

http://postimg.org/image/haiii0cjt/

**Matlab function Code**

```
function[returnValues] = Blocks_Threads_Test(blocks,threads)

%1  Create Cuda Kernel Object

k = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('BlocksThreads.ptx', 'BlocksThreads.cu','BlocksThreads');

%2 Set Object properties

k.GridSize = [blocks];
k.ThreadBlockSize = [threads];

%3 Set Argument Variables

gpu_Values = gpuArray(ones(4,blocks*threads));

[data] = feval(k, gpu_Values);


returnValues = gather(data);
```

**Cuda Matlab Code**

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void BlocksThreads(double *values) 
{
    unsigned int bx = blockIdx.x;
    unsigned int tx = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned long int globalID = (bx*blockDim.x) + tx;


    values[(bx*blockDim.x) + (tx*4) + 0] = bx; //Block Number
    values[(bx*blockDim.x) + (tx*4) + 1] = tx; //Thread Number
    values[(bx*blockDim.x) + (tx*4) + 2] = globalID; 
    values[(bx*blockDim.x) + (tx*4) + 3] = blockDim.x; //Threads/Block
}
```

Does anyone know why the id values in Matlab for the threads, blocks, and globals are all over the place? Not to mention the Matrix doesn't even fill out the entire way.

If it's relevant this is what I'm running

- Win 7 64
- VS 2012
- Matlab 2013b 64
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 770
- Compute 3.0

Comment: Please, don't provide images or results as external links. When those links will be broken, it would be difficult for future users to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I couldn't post the pictures directly the because of my lack of reputation :(.  As soon as I can get 10 points I'll re-edit the post and upload the images directly for future users.

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of `values[(bx*blockDim.x) + (tx*4) + k]` with `k=0,1,2,3`? Should you change it to `values[4*globalID + k]` with `k=0,1,2,3`?

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  The problem was my indexing equation in cuda for the return values.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong indexing of the `values` matrix. Change

```
values[(bx*blockDim.x) + (tx*4) + k] with k=0,1,2,3
```

to

```
values[4*globalID + k] with k=0,1,2,3
```